# MySQL - Login fails with incorrect match of case for username

Tags: mysql

I am unable to login to mysql unless I provide exact case match for a user I have in my database.

After looking into the issue I believe my problem is with the collation but I am not sure.  I tried to alter collation for the mysql.user table, User column to be latin1_swedish_ci but still could not get it to recognize alternate cases for usernames when I try to login.

My new username is admin ( all lowercase)

The command I am running is

```
mysql -u admiN -p    <------ with username ending in a capital letter
```

Prior to running the command I ran the SQL statement below.

Here is the command I ran with apparently no effect (Original Collation was utf8_bin)

```
ALTER TABLE `user` CHANGE `User` `User` CHAR(16) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '';
```

Each time I get the following response.

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admiN'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

Only when I login with all lowercase for the username do I succeed in entering into mysql.

Am I missing something else here to get it working?  How do I change the mysql configuration to accept case insensitive usernames?

Comment: Run FLUSH PRIVILEGES after changing it,maybe even restart mysql.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be changing attributes of internal tables like this.

Comment: I did attempt to both suggestions but it seems to be unsuccessful.  To Barmar's comment I agree. It seems to be not responsive either way.  I thought to modify the table because I did not know any where else to apply collation settings.  I'll try another way.

Comment: The table `user` is indexed. Changing the collation does not automatically reindex the table. Try to reindex or rebuild the index. I'd suggest use a collation closer to the default `utf8_bin` such as `utf8_general_ci`.

Comment: I think it would be best to keep the original `user` table and use collation in index. Check this out for more info https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=826.

Comment: Still trying on the suggestions.  I tried adding a new index but for some reason I was not able to get mysql to recognize the collation in the index statement.  I am running 5.6.17 under wampserver.  Is there any way to change all column indices or find what table is causing this issue to occur?